# How to connect multiple audio output channels for use with PyAudio?

Tags: python, audio, playback, pyaudio

I'm new to PyAudio and audio manipulation so this is a really basic question I haven't found the answer for -- PyAudio gives you the option of sending sound to different channels via a channel map, but how do you get those different channels hooked up to your computer/python?

Is it as simple as, for example, pairing a bluetooth speaker and thus having my computer's internal speakers as one channel and the bluetooth speaker as a second?

(Ultimately I'd like to play 2 .wav files simultaneously but separately on 2 different outputs. If there's an easier way of doing this than with PyAudio, open to hearing about that, too!)

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this may be possible using [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.10/#). See link for install details.

`sounddevice` provides an easy way to list different input/output audio devices using `sd.query_devices()`

```
>>> print sd.query_devices()
   0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input, MME (2 in, 0 out)
>  1 Jack Mic (IDT High Definition A, MME (2 in, 0 out)
   2 Microphone Array (IDT High Defi, MME (2 in, 0 out)
   3 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output, MME (0 in, 2 out)
<  4 Speakers / Headphones (IDT High, MME (0 in, 2 out)
   5 Communication Headphones (IDT H, MME (0 in, 2 out)
```

Here device id (4) is output device (speakers). I don't have `bluetooth` configured. But if you have, it should show in the list.

Once both output devices are listed, you can simply redirect them using 
`sd.play(data_array, sampling_frequency, device=device_id_)`

While `sounddevice` has limitation of blocking IO while playback is in progress, I believe it can be overcome by the use of threading.

NOTE: Following code is not tested on two different devices. Let me know if it works.

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import threading
from threading import Thread

def audioFunc1():
    audio1 = "audio1.wav"
    data1, fs1 = sf.read(audio1, dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data1, fs1, device=3)   #speakers

def audioFunc2():
    audio2 = "audio2.wav"
    data2, fs2 = sf.read(audio2, dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data2, fs2, device=10)  #headset

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = audioFunc1).start()
    Thread(target = audioFunc2).start()
```

Comment: This works, as long as you run the script with the -i flag

Comment: Weird... if I put a sleep statement between the two Thread calls, sd.play() will stop the audio1.wav when it starts audio2.wav.  This is how sd.play() is designed to work... but somehow, this code actually works!